# error when trying to enable php on mac osx mojave Syntax error on line 281 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Tags: php, macos, apache, syntax

i am following this guide to enable php on my mac osx mojave [How to install Apache, MySQL, PHP on macOS Mojave 10.14](https://www.dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14)

This is the error

```
Syntax error on line 281 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:</Directory>
```

line 281 is the final line of code in the following block

```
<Directory "/Users/brandondjuric/Sites/">
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

here is a larger block of the same code

```
#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory,     but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
# DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
# <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
DocumentRoot "/Users/brandondjuric/Sites/"
<Directory "/Users/brandondjuric/Sites/">
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All"
```

Comment: Try to remove the last slash, leave just /Users/brandondjuric/Sites and let me know if worked